# Combine only certain rows in dataframe effeciently

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that has the beginning and end times of certain activities in subsequent rows that have the same id and activity. Every now and then there is a row without an end that I want to drop evtl. (id 3 & 5 in this example). The rows that are paired (with id/act pairs: 1/10,2/10 & 1/10 at a different time) can be merged, i.e. the second row can be dropped.  I can add the end times simply by shifting one column, but I am having a hard time getting rid of the unnecessary rows without iterating through the whole dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,10,20],[1,10,25],[2,10,40],[2,10,41],[3,10,42],[1,10,45],[1,10,45],[5,10,50]], columns=['id','act','time'])
df["time 2"]=df["time"].shift(-1)
```

Comment: Can you show a before and after of your anticipated result?

Answer (score 0):

Thank yo uso much for the quick reply, but I actually fixed this myself with a very simple solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,10,20],[1,10,25],[2,10,40],[2,10,41],[3,10,42],[1,10,45],[1,10,45],[5,10,50]], columns=['id','act','time'])

id  act  time
0   1   10    20
1   1   10    25
2   2   10    40
3   2   10    41
4   3   10    42
5   1   10    45
6   1   10    45
7   5   10    50
df["end"]=df["time"].shift(-1)
df["id 2"]=df["id"].shift(-1)
df["act 2"]=df["act"].shift(-1)
df.drop(df.index[len(df)-1],inplace=True)

   id  act  time  time 2  id 2  act 2
0   1   10    20    25.0   1.0   10.0
1   1   10    25    40.0   2.0   10.0
2   2   10    40    41.0   2.0   10.0
3   2   10    41    42.0   3.0   10.0
4   3   10    42    45.0   1.0   10.0
5   1   10    45    45.0   1.0   10.0
6   1   10    45    50.0   5.0   10.0

df=df.loc[(df["id"]==df["id 2"])== (df["act"]==df["act 2"])]
df.drop(columns=["id 2","act 2"],axis=0,inplace=True)

   id  act  time   end
0   1   10    20  25.0
2   2   10    40  41.0
5   1   10    45  45.0
```